# Using JPA Criteria Query, how to get the sysdate + x

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA Criteria Query hibernate-jpa-2.0-api (1.0.1.Final).

I want to get the `currentDate() + x` from the database using my criteria query (sysdate + any value(x) specified ).

How can i use the `cb.currentDate()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sql query to get the date time. However you can achieve this through the hibernate API

```
Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select SYSDATE param from dual").addScalar("param", Hibernate.TIMESTAMP).uniqueResult(); return new DateTime(timestamp);
```

Comment: Jijo wants to use Criteria Query… not a plain SQL query. It's not a big deal to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom dialect that registers a custom function:

package de.enerko.aaw2.persistence.dialect;

```
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class OracleSpatialDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
    public OracleSpatialDialect() {
        this.registerColumnType(Types.OTHER, "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY");
        this.registerFunction("add_days", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, "", "+", ""));
    }
}
```

Specify it in persistence.xml or whatever technique you use for building the entity manager:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="OracleSpatialDialect" />
```

and than use it like so:

```
builder.function("add_days", Date.class, builder.currentDate(), builder.literal(1))
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Michael.